# How to avoid superfluous Wicket log warnings when using field-specific FeedbackLabels?

Tags: java, validation, wicket, feedbackpanel

I'm using "FeedbackLabels" to show component-specific validation messages, based on ideas and code in this blog post: [User friendly form validation with Wicket](http://stuq.nl/weblog/2008-09-03/user-friendly-form-validation-with-wicket).

Problem is, pages using such FeedbackLabels for validation messages flood the log with superfluous warnings:

```
2012-05-04 10:43:32,824 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-6] WARN  org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebSession - Component-targetted feedback message was left unrendered. This could be because you are missing a FeedbackPanel on the page.  Message: [FeedbackMessage message = "Tilille on pakollinen tieto", reporter = toAccount, level = ERROR]
2012-05-04 10:43:32,824 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-6] WARN  org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebSession - Component-targetted feedback message was left unrendered. This could be because you are missing a FeedbackPanel on the page.  Message: [FeedbackMessage message = "Tililtä on pakollinen tieto", reporter = fromAccount, level = ERROR]
2012-05-04 10:43:32,824 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-6] WARN  org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebSession - Component-targetted feedback message was left unrendered. This could be because you are missing a FeedbackPanel on the page.  Message: [FeedbackMessage message = "Viitenro on pakollinen tieto", reporter = reference, level = ERROR]
2012-05-04 10:43:35,039 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-6] WARN  org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebSession - Component-targetted feedback message was left unrendered. This could be because you are missing a FeedbackPanel on the page.  Message: [FeedbackMessage message = "Tilille on pakollinen tieto", reporter = toAccount, level = ERROR]
[...]
```

Wicket claims that:

> Component-targetted feedback message was left unrendered. This could
>   be because you are missing a FeedbackPanel on the page.

Thing is, as you can see in the screenshot, those messages **were** rendered (in the FeedbackLabels accompanying each  field), and I **do** also have a FeedbackPanel on the page (but it filters the component-targetted messages, using ComponentFeedbackMessageFilter, so that they aren't shown twice).

[image]

In any case, these log messages clearly aren't useful. **How can I make Wicket shut up about this**? (Without resorting to brute force methods like changing logging level to FATAL.) Should something be fixed in Daan's FeedbackLabel implementation perhaps (see below)?

---

Appendix: Basically FeedbackLabel (extends Label) checks if the related component has a feedback message, and if so, displays it. If you can't be bothered loading the code from the [article](http://stuq.nl/weblog/2008-09-03/user-friendly-form-validation-with-wicket), here's the relevant part:

```
// (Author of this code is Daan, StuQ.nl
// it's licenced under Apache 2.0 license.)
@Override
protected void onBeforeRender() {
    super.onBeforeRender();

    if(component.getFeedbackMessage()!=null) {
        if(this.text!=null) {
            setDefaultModel(this.text);
        } else {
            setDefaultModel(new Model(component.getFeedbackMessage().getMessage()));
        }

        this.add(new AttributeModifier("class", true, new Model("feedbackLabel " + component.getFeedbackMessage().getLevelAsString())));
    } else {
        setDefaultModel(new Model(""));
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, using Wicket 1.4, if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FeedbackMessage has a markRendered() functon. I would add a call to this for each message that whas added to a Label. Seethe code of the FeedbackPanel.

Comment: Worked great, thanks! (Tweaked FeedbackLabel's onBeforeRender() so that markRendered() is called  inside the component.getFeedbackMessage() != null condition.) I guess I should add a comment on the blog post, suggesting this improvement, in case the original author or some other people still use the same FeedbackLabel code.